# Numeric sort on specific position/column + saving "classic" sort on previous columns

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

Here is a sample of the file I have :

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;1

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;11

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;2

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;60;1

C;S;tous;PMJ200;1;40;1

(some other files have thousands of lines !)

All I want is the last column to be numeric-sorted like 1 2 ... 9 10 11 etcetc BUT it must save the original "classical" sorting on 6 first columns ! So the result should be :

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;1

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;2

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;11

C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;60;1

C;S;tous;PMJ200;1;40;1

Tried everything I could, and didnt find anything usefull on google :(

(nb : empty lines are just for correct display on stackoverflow)

Thx in advance for help guys !

Answer (score 1):

So you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Attention!
if [ -f tosort.tmp ]
then
    rm tosort.tmp
fi


if [ -f tosort_done.tmp ]
then
    rm tosort_done.tmp
fi


if [ -f result.out ]
then
    rm result.out
fi


# And a data file must contain a last "end" line.



nosort_previous_symb=""

while read line_data
do

    tosort_symb=`echo $line_data | rev | cut -d";" -f1-1 | rev`
    nosort_symb=`echo $line_data | rev | cut -d";" -f2- | rev`


    if [[ "$nosort_previous_symb" == "" || "$nosort_previous_symb" == "$nosort_symb"  ]]
    then

        echo $tosort_symb >> tosort.tmp

        #refresh nosort_symb
        nosort_previous_symb="$nosort_symb"


    else


        #old nosort_symb to out
        cat tosort.tmp | sort -nk 1 >  tosort_done.tmp

        while read tosort_symb_done
        do

            echo ""$nosort_previous_symb";"$tosort_symb_done"" >> result.out

        done < tosort_done.tmp


        # new nosort
        echo $tosort_symb > tosort.tmp


        #refresh no sort
        nosort_previous_symb="$nosort_symb"

    fi  


done < data


# Attention!    
rm -f *.tmp


exit
```

Add for exapmle "end" to your data file to use:

```
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;1
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;11
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;2
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;60;1
C;S;tous;PMJ200;1;40;1
end
```

In the result:

```
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;1
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;2
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;40;11
C;S;tous;PMJ100;1;60;1
C;S;tous;PMJ200;1;40;1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood you. In bash you can use:

```
cat data  | tr  " " "\n" | sort -t ";" -nk 7
```

"data" is a file with your data.

Comment: Original question wasn't precise enough, edited the lines I want to sort !
thx for answering anyway :)

Comment: I see. You can delete a "tr" command in this case.
Good luck)

Comment: Yep ^^ but still can't do my sort :(